# Format PHP simpleXML file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument, sitemap

Im creating simple PHP code to generate sitemap.xml file, but the problem is, that the file is unformatted. If the file was smaller, I could look at it in browser, but it has about 1,5 MB and Chrome just gives up while loading it (IE loads it and you can view it, but its lagging really hard).

I googled and tried different solutions (even from this site), but none of them worked, so Im humbly asking for your help. Also Im using the newest PHP version and my server runs on Unix based OS if thats important.

Here is code Im using (there are couple thousands (15.000+) rows in the table, so XML file is pretty long:

```
$xml = '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

$xml .= "<url>";
$xml .= "<loc>MY.URL.COM/</loc>";
$xml .= "<changefreq>always</changefreq>";
$xml .= "<priority>1.00</priority>";
$xml .= "</url>";

$xml .= "<url>";
$xml .= "<loc>MY.URL.COM/upload.php</loc>";
$xml .= "<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>";
$xml .= "<priority>0.80</priority>";
$xml .= "</url>";

$select = dbquery("SELECT * FROM MY TABLE");
while ($data = dbarray($select)) {
    $xml .= "<url>";
    $xml .= "<loc>MY.URL.COM/?id=".$data['id']."</loc>";
    $xml .= "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
    $xml .= "<priority>0.50</priority>";
    $xml .= "</url>";
}

$xml .= '</urlset>';

$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($sxml->asXML());
$dom->saveXML("sitemap.xml");
```

Also, every time after new page is added Im running this code to append it to sitemap file and its appending it into one row, so need to fix that too.
Im trying both codes separately, so Im sure the first one doesnt format the document at all.

```
$sitemap = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$url = $sitemap->addChild('url');
$url->addChild("loc", "MY.URL.COM/?id=".$get_id['id']);
$url->addChild("changefreq", "daily");
$url->addChild("priority", "0.50");
$sitemap->asXML("sitemap.xml");
```

By Unreadable I mean its saved in one line like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url><loc>MY.URL.COM?id=1</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.50</priority></url><url><loc>MY.URL.COM?id=2</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.50</priority></url><url><loc>MY.URL.COM?id=5</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.50</priority></url><url><loc>MY.URL.COM?id=7</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.50</priority></url></urlset>
```

Instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>MY.URL.COM?id=1</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>MY.URL.COM?id=2</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>MY.URL.COM?id=5</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>MY.URL.COM?id=7</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

**

### WORKING CODE:

**

```
$xml = "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'>";

$select = dbquery("SELECT * FROM MY TABLE");
while ($data = dbarray($select)) {
    $xml .= "<url>";
    $xml .= "<loc>MY.URL.COM/?id=".$data['id']."</loc>";
    $xml .= "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
    $xml .= "<priority>0.50</priority>";
}

$xml .= '</urlset>';
$sitemap = simplexml_load_file($xml);
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->save("sitemap.xml");
```

Code to append to existing xml file:

```
$sitemap = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$url = $sitemap->addChild('url');
$url->addChild("loc", "MY.URL.COM/?id=".$get_id['id']);
$url->addChild("changefreq", "daily");
$url->addChild("priority", "0.50");

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($sitemap->asXML());
$dom->save('sitemap.xml');
```

Comment: By "unformatted", you mean it lacks readable indentation and linebreaks?

Comment: Exactly. Ill edit the question.

Comment: The `$dom->formatOutput = true` method you've used is the typical way to handle it. What does it do instead of what you expect it to ( that is, how does it _not work_?)

Comment: Also please post a more complete example of what the string `$xml` looks like before you load it into `SimpleXML`.

Comment: Added what you asked. Basically that WHILE goes throu whole DB, in which are about 15.000+ results. And second code is there just to append to already existing XML file, So I dont have to always go trough whole DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit Start

```php
//you don't need simplexml
// $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml); // can use the xml string
$dom->save("sitemap.xml"); // need to use save() rather than saveXML
```

#### Edit End

The code that you have written for the first time will do a proper formatting. Problem will arise when you add a new element/node to `sitemap.xml` using simplexml.

If you want a properly formatted XML, you will need to save it using `DOMDocument` every time, the same one that you are doing initially.

**What you are doing**

```
$sitemap = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$url = $sitemap->addChild('url');
$url->addChild("loc", "MY.URL.COM/?id=".$get_id['id']);
$url->addChild("changefreq", "daily");
$url->addChild("priority", "0.50");
$sitemap->asXML("sitemap.xml");
```

**Try changing it to this:**

```
$sitemap = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$url = $sitemap->addChild('url');
$url->addChild("loc", "MY.URL.COM/?id=".$get_id['id']);
$url->addChild("changefreq", "daily");
$url->addChild("priority", "0.50");

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0',LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($sitemap->asXML());
$dom->saveXML('sitemap.xml');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, the first code is not doing a propper formatting. Im trying it on dev page without the second part of the code, and the xml file is unformatted :(

Comment: Ok, now it works (even with load ($sxe....). THe problem was with save function. Ill try it to append too. Ok, tried and works. Ill add the working code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to look at is if server where your code is running is Unix/Linux it'll use Unix end of lines (LF) which if viewed with Windows editors or browser may not show right as they expect (CR-LF).

Comment: Well, its shows ok in browser (Im tesing the code on dev version which doesnt have that many records in DB, so it actually loads). Is there a way to fake it? As my server is Unix based.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fake it but if you want to check if the file has cr-lf or lf only a simple if (str_pos("\l\n", $xml) { print "Windows EOL"} should show you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fake it but if you want to check if the file has cr-lf or lf only a simple if (str_pos("\r\n", $xml) { print "Windows EOL"} should show you. you can also try running your saved file through unix2dos and see what you get. I've also written a PHP version of the Unix utils EOL tools which you can find on GitHub https://github.com/Dragonrun1/peol. They are made to run from CLI and need composer install but the main lib/Converter class can be used directly if needed. Had a need for this myself so decided to try writing them. Cut off my edit above.

Comment: Thank you for info, anyway its fixed now. I tried to add \r\n manually while creating the file, but function saveXML just deletes those.